# Proper way to send an object from a post to php and loop over

Tags: php, json

I'm attempting to make a post request to a php server.
I need to pass over some specs in an "object"
I pass the parameter:

```
files: "[{qty: 25, file: 'LabelProof_1148_1.pdf'}, {qty: 50, file:'LabelProof_1148_2.pdf'}]"
```

I can access the parameter in php like so:

```
$files = $request->files;
```

When I try to loop over it I get an error:

```
   foreach ($files as $f) {
        return($f);
    }
```

I attempt to decode it:

```
$files = json_decode($request->files);
```

This still gives me an error that

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `var_dump($files);` please, so we can see what's actually in it after you decode it

Comment: You appear to be sending a string, which isn't even valid JSON. How did you come to send that particular data format?!

Comment: Use a service such as https://jsonlint.com to check whether your hand-written JSON is valid or not, before you try to use it.

Comment: @ADyson thank you I was indeed passing invalid json.  The string was my way of trying to "fix" the json but the json itself was incorrect originally.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To convert JSON string to JSON format, you should fix that string format from :

```json
[{qty: 25, file: 'LabelProof_1148_1.pdf'}, {qty: 50, file:'LabelProof_1148_2.pdf'}]
```

to:

```json
[{"qty": 25, "file": "LabelProof_1148_1.pdf"}, {"qty": 50, "file":"LabelProof_1148_2.pdf"}]
```

You can fix that with some string replacement like this:

```php
<?php
//$request = new stdClass();
$request->files = "[{qty: 25, file: 'LabelProof_1148_1.pdf'}, {qty: 50, file:'LabelProof_1148_2.pdf'}]";
$files = str_replace("'", '"', $request->files);
$files = str_replace('qty', '"qty"', $files);
$files = str_replace('file', '"file"', $files);
$files = json_decode($files, true);
foreach ($files as $f) {
    var_dump($f);
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: That fixes this specific, exact string, but won't work universally. OP should just provide valid JSON in the input to begin with.